# How can I safely change resturl for glusterfs storage class on my Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, glusterfs, kubernetes-pvc

Heketi pod was restarted on our Kubernetes Cluster and now I'm struggling with how to change glusterfs storage class resturl with new heketi endpoint.
What are the safest options without any data loss on our PVCs?
I was able to recreate Kubernetes Cluster v1.11.10 on our test environment and start investigating on it. When I tried to edit storage class I got:

```
"StorageClass.storage.k8s.io "glusterfs" is invalid: parameters Forbidden: updates to parameters are forbidden."
```

We are using Kubernetes v.1.11.10.
I tried to create new storage class with correct heketi endpoint, but I couldn't edit PVCs:

```
PersistentVolumeClaim "test-pvc" is invalid: spec: Forbidden: is immutable after creation except resources.requests for bound claims
```

I was able only to delete old storage class and create new with correct heketi resturl.

Comment: have you used pod IP or Service name as an endpoint? Can you "kubectl describe" your storage class?

Comment: @VasilyAngapov unfortunately storage class was created with pod IP instead of service.
```Name:                  gluster-sc
IsDefaultClass:        No
Annotations:           <none>
Provisioner:           kubernetes.io/glusterfs
Parameters:            resturl=http://10.244.3.13:8080,restuser=,restuserkey=
AllowVolumeExpansion:  <unset>
MountOptions:          <none>
ReclaimPolicy:         Delete
VolumeBindingMode:     Immediate
Events:                <none>```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try to use "kubectl replace" like that:

```
kubectl replace -f storage-class.yaml --force
```

Just make sure that you use Heketi Service name as a REST URL to avoid further such issues.

Comment: thanks for help. I found out why resturl was hardcoded with IP. When I tried to use  service name instead of IP I got DNS resolution errors like: ```failed to create volume: failed to create volume: Post http://heketi.default:8080/volumes: dial tcp: lookup heketi on 192.168.22.245:53: no such host```. But in debug pod I didn't have such issues with name resolution. ```/home # curl http://heketi:8080/volumes ... {"volumes":["04ee4d465cee3979bd52a57049d6"}```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here why it's not working with internal DNS heketi service name
[Set up Heketi Rest URL in Storage Class issue](https://github.com/gluster/gluster-kubernetes/issues/570)